# Cannot get C++ Project Euler #2 quite right

Tags: c++

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

I have referred to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818186/cant-quite-get-project-euler-problem-2-figured-out) too but it didn't help much with my case.

I got the sum of the even valued terms when I limit the sequence to 10. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x = 0, y = 1, z, sumeven = 0;

for (int stop=1; stop <= 5; stop++)
{
    z = x + y;
    x = y;
    y = z;
    cout << y << endl;
   
    if (y % 2 == 0)
    {
        sumeven += y;
    }
}
cout << "The total is: "<< sumeven << endl;
return 0;
}
```

This is my output to the above code:

```
1
2
3
5
8
The total is: 10
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

The problem occurs when I input the 4,000,000 value. This is the code. The only difference is I did not print the sequence.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int x = 0, y = 1, z, sumeven = 0;

for (int stop=1; stop <= 4000000; stop++)
{
    z = x + y;
    x = y;
    y = z;
   
    if (y % 2 == 0)
    {
        sumeven += y;
    }
}
cout << "The total is: "<< sumeven << endl;
return 0;
}
```

This is the output to the above code.

```
The total is: -1833689714
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I don't understand why my code seems to work perfectly with the smaller sequence but not with the 4 million inputted when the code is exactly the same.

I just started Intro to Programming bridging classes at uni for a fast track degree in Computer Science. They're cramming a semester's worth of lessons in 2 weekends and I'd like to be competent with the basics of C++ by the end of it so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are overflowing an `int` datatype, which probably has a maximum value of `2^31-1`. Try redefining `sumeven` as a `unsigned long long` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You interpreted the problem wrong. You're checking up to the 4.000.000th element of the fibonacci sequence while the problem asks for elements lower than 4.000.000

Just change

```
for (int stop=1; stop <= 4000000; stop++)
```

To

```
while(y < 4000000)
```

Edit:
In case you don't understand why the numbers were negative, it's a case of integer overflow:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: I just reread the problem and realised. It's 5am and I feel like such a twit for agonizing about it for hours. Knowing about integer overflow is very useful though. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, every programmer gets stuck with these kinds of small problems once in a while :). Btw, you can upvote the answer if you feel like it.

Comment: You rightfully deserve my upvote but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points for it to show publicly. I'm sorry :(

Comment: Scratch that then, i'm new here too.